# Combine 2 Strategies. Enter only when both in same direction?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

- I usually combine multiple strategies and test them.
- When i use the `and` logic, the strategy enters only when `buyCondition` *(be it **ta.crossover** OR **>/< value** type logic)* of both strategies align on top of each other, which is not what i want. I want the strategy to enter when the **"direction" of both strategies is the same**, i.e. both are long/short.
  I understand that this involves converting the

> `buyCondition` to `dir = 1`

but this becomes a challenge since i am an amateur.
I want a standard logic that can be applied to all strategies which could change the `buyCondition` to `dir = 1` and i could use it as a template in the code.

- It should also incorporate that it doesnt re-enter if the signal has arrived previously i.e. `buyCondition and not buyCondition [1]` logic.

*Some sample codes i have found here and there are below, dont know if it helps:*

**1. Sample Code 1**

```
pos = int(na)
iff_3 = close[1] > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) and close < nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) ? -1 : nz(pos[1], 0)
pos := close[1] < nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) and close > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) ? 1 : iff_3

color_1 = pos == -1 ? color.red : pos == 1 ? color.lime : color.blue
//patr=plot(xATRTrailingStop, color=color, linewidth=2, title="ATR Trailing Stop", transp=0)

// Deternine if we are currently LONG
isLong = false
isLong := nz(isLong[1], false)

// Determine if we are currently SHORT
isShort = false
isShort := nz(isShort[1], false)

//Trading
// Buy only if the buy signal is triggered and we are not already long
LONG = not isLong and pos == 1


// Sell only if the sell signal is triggered and we are not already short   
SHORT = not isShort and pos == -1

if LONG
    isLong := true
    isShort := false
    isShort

if SHORT
    isLong := false
    isShort := true
    isShort
```

**2. Sample Code 2 (here i dont want a lookback)**

```
//@version=5
strategy("Strategy Loop Direction Template, Alam", overlay=true)

lookback = input.int(title = "Lookback Period", defval = 10)

islong  = strategy.position_size > 0 
isshort = strategy.position_size < 0 
isnotin = strategy.position_size == 0

///////////////// MACD Strategy Calculations

fast_length = input.int(title="Fast Length", defval=12)
slow_length = input.int(title="Slow Length", defval=26)
src = input.source(title="Source", defval=close)
signal_length = input.int(title="Signal Smoothing", minval = 1, maxval = 50, defval = 9)
sma_source = input.string(title="Oscillator MA Type", defval="EMA", options=["SMA", "EMA"])
sma_signal = input.string(title="Signal Line MA Type", defval="EMA", options=["SMA", "EMA"])

macd_lb    = input.bool(title = "Use MACD Lookback?", defval = false)

// Calculating
fast_ma = sma_source == "SMA" ? ta.sma(src, fast_length) : ta.ema(src, fast_length)
slow_ma = sma_source == "SMA" ? ta.sma(src, slow_length) : ta.ema(src, slow_length)
macd = fast_ma - slow_ma
signal = sma_signal == "SMA" ? ta.sma(macd, signal_length) : ta.ema(macd, signal_length)
hist = macd - signal

macd_L = ta.crossover(macd,signal) and macd < 0
macd_S = ta.crossunder(macd,signal) and macd > 0

///////////////// RSI Strategy Calculations

rsi_len = input.int(title="RSI Length", defval=14)
rsi_lb  = input.bool(title = "Use RSI Lookback?", defval = false)

rsi = ta.rsi(close,rsi_len)

rsi_L = ta.crossover(rsi,30)
rsi_S = ta.crossunder(rsi,70)

/////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Define Variables

bool macd_LC = false
bool macd_SC = false
bool rsi_LC  = false
bool rsi_SC  = false

// Loop Checker

for i = 0 to lookback by 1
// Long Checks
    if (macd_lb ? macd_L[i] : macd_L)
        macd_LC := true
    if (rsi_lb ? rsi_L[i] : rsi_L)
        rsi_LC := true        
// Short Checks
    if (macd_lb ? macd_S[i] : macd_S)
        macd_SC := true
    if (rsi_lb ? rsi_S[i] : rsi_S)
        rsi_SC := true  

// Long and Short Conditions

longCondition   = macd_LC and rsi_LC
shortCondition  = macd_SC and rsi_SC

// Entries

if longCondition and (isnotin or isshort)
    strategy.entry("Enter Long", strategy.long ,comment = "Long Entry", alert_message = "Enter Long Order")
    strategy.close("Enter Short", comment = "Close Short", alert_message = "Close Short Order")

if shortCondition and (isnotin or islong)
    strategy.entry("Enter Short", strategy.short ,comment = "Short Entry", alert_message = "Enter Short Order")
    strategy.close("Enter Long", comment = "Close Long", alert_message = "Close Long Order")
```

**3. Sample Code 3**

```
// INPUT ============================================================================================================
fastMALen = input.int(defval = 21, title = 'Fast/Slow SMA Length', minval = 1, inline = 'MA Length', group = 'Strategy')
slowMALen = input.int(defval = 49, title = '', minval = 1, tooltip = 'How many candles back to calculte the fast/slow SMA.', inline = 'MA Length', group = 'Strategy')

// LOGIC ============================================================================================================
fastMA = ta.sma(close, fastMALen)
slowMA = ta.sma(close, slowMALen)

bool openLongPosition = longTradesEnabled and ta.crossover(fastMA, slowMA)
bool openShortPosition = shortTradesEnabled and ta.crossunder(fastMA, slowMA)

bool closeLongPosition = longTradesEnabled and ta.crossunder(fastMA, slowMA)
bool closeShortPosition = shortTradesEnabled and ta.crossover(fastMA, slowMA)

// PLOT =============================================================================================================
var fastColor = color.new(color.yellow, 0)
plot(series = fastMA, title = 'Fast SMA', color = fastColor, linewidth = 1, style = plot.style_line)
var slowColor = color.new(color.orange, 0)
plot(series = slowMA, title = 'Slow SMA', color = slowColor, linewidth = 1, style = plot.style_line)

//
// ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒
// ENTRY ============================================================================================================

// LOGIC ============================================================================================================
// the open signals when not already into a position
bool validOpenLongPosition = openLongPosition and not (strategy.opentrades.size(strategy.opentrades - 1) > 0)
bool validOpenShortPosition = openShortPosition and not (strategy.opentrades.size(strategy.opentrades - 1) < 0)

bool longIsActive = validOpenLongPosition or strategy.opentrades.size(strategy.opentrades - 1) > 0 and not closeLongPosition
bool shortIsActive = validOpenShortPosition or strategy.opentrades.size(strategy.opentrades - 1) < 0 and not closeShortPosition

// PLOT =============================================================================================================
var buyColor = color.new(color.green, 0)
var sellColor = color.new(color.red, 0)
var textColor = color.new(color.white, 0)
if (validOpenLongPosition)
    label.new(x = bar_index, y = na, text = 'Buy', yloc = yloc.belowbar, color = buyColor, style = label.style_label_up, textcolor = textColor)
if (validOpenShortPosition)
    label.new(x = bar_index, y = na, text = 'Sell', yloc = yloc.abovebar, color = sellColor, style = label.style_label_down, textcolor = textColor)

// ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒
// POSITION ORDERS ==================================================================================================

// LOGIC ============================================================================================================
// close on trend reversal
if (closeLongPosition)
    strategy.close(id = 'Long Entry', comment = 'Close Long', alert_message = 'Long: Closed at market price')

// close on trend reversal
if (closeShortPosition)
    strategy.close(id = 'Short Entry', comment = 'Close Short', alert_message = 'Short: Closed at market price')

// getting into LONG position
if (openLongPosition)
    strategy.entry(id = 'Long Entry', direction = strategy.long, alert_message = 'Long(' + syminfo.ticker + '): Started')

// getting into SHORT position
if (openShortPosition)
    strategy.entry(id = 'Short Entry', direction = strategy.short, alert_message = 'Short(' + syminfo.ticker + '): Started')
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a template as each script is different.

Here is one approach for your general problem which should help with most of other cases.

Assume script 1 triggers an entry when `script1_entry = ta.crossover(a, b)` and script 2 triggers an entry when `script2_entry = ta.crossunder(rsi, c)`.

Say your entry condition is when script 1 and 2 are in the buy, and if the price goes below EMA 50.

The way you can check if the script 1 and script 2 are in the long position when the price goes below EMA 50 is using the comparasion operators:

```
script3_entry = (a > b) and (rsi < c) and ta.crossunder(close, ema50)
```

`(a > b)` will be `true` if the script 1 is long, and `(rsi < c)` will be `true` if the script 2 is long.